# fedora 23 with kernel-4.4.2-300 shut down too slowly

Tags: fedora, fedora-23

I am using fedora 23 with a Dell xps-13-9350, and for wifi reason, I upgrade kerenl to 4.4+ (first in the f24 repo, and then vanilla, at last the updates-testing repo). For all the test, there was an issue, it just cann't power off immediately, nearly ten minutes later, and when I cover the screen, no hunging up. I tried "shut down -h now", "halt -p", and the GUI button, result same.

When I downgrade to kernel 4.3.5, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This isn't a definitive answer, but rather some things to try.

What you want to able to see is the various boot and shutdown messages that are normally hidden behind the graphical boot [and shutdown] screen.

During grub boot, override the default and get the menu. You can [temporarily] override the options by editing the given menu entry.

Remove the words `rhgb` and `quiet`.

Now, you'll get *tons* of text messages. On shutdown, this may give you a clue.

You can also edit `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and remove these words for a more permanent solution. FYI, I never use `rhgb` or `quiet` because I've had too many similar situations.

Also, check your system logs (e.g. `/var/log/messages`) and `journalctl`.

The usual suspect for behavior like you're describing is `systemd`.

It is a collection of utilities, but it also has a component in the kernel. In fedora, `systemd` and the kernel get revved together to maintain compatibility with one another.

By pulling a newer kernel from fc24 while your `systemd` comes from fc23, that may be the problem. The older `systemd` can't handle the newer kernel. A newer `systemd` can usually handle an older kernel but not always the reverse

So, if you want the newer kernel, you may have to use `fedup` [or `dnf`] to upgrade to fc24.

Of course, doing so can have its hazards, so be sure to have a full backup first.

If you do upgrade to fc24, some of your earlier kernels will still be there.

Also, if after the fc24 upgrade, if you still have an issue, you can file a bug report. With your current hybrid approach you're in the "we do not support this" category.